# Android Volley Post Param works only for file

Tags: android, android-volley

First of all, I have been needed upload file using Volley library and I find one and it works great. However, if I do not set file it does not work. It means if `model.getFile()` is null all other entities do not requested.

```
public class MultipartRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {

private MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;
private HashMap<String, String> mParams;

QuestionModel model;
Activity activity;

public MultipartRequest(String url, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, Response.Listener<String> listener, QuestionModel model, Activity activity) {
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);
    mListener = listener;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.model = model;
    buildMultipartEntity();
}

private void buildMultipartEntity() {
    try {
        entity.addPart("theme_id", new StringBody(model.getThemeID()));
        if (model.getText() != null) {
            entity.addPart("text", new StringBody(model.getText()));
        } else {
            entity.addPart("text", new StringBody("file"));
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        VolleyLog.e("UnsupportedEncodingException");
    }
    if (model.getFile() != null) {            
            entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(new File(model.getFile())));
    }
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String creds = String.format("%s:%s", Const.PHONE_NUMBER_VALUE, Const.getPassword());
    String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    params.put("Authorization", auth);
    if (model.getFile() != null) {
        params.put("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    } else {
        params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    }
    return params;
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return entity.getContentType().getValue();
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        entity.writeTo(bos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}

@Override
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, "utf-8"));
        return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
    }
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
    mListener.onResponse(response.toString());
}
}
```

Thank you for your help.
**EDITED:**
if i removed `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` that changing to when file did not set it worked but if text is cyrilic not working in this case

Comment: Why are you tampering around with Content-Type then?

Comment: @greenapps i used Cyrillic letter wherefore i will change to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" if file is not seted

Comment: You did not answer my question.

Comment: With or without file you should use the same content type. You did not tell where you use cyrillic but it has nothing to do with content type.